# How can I put ImageButton in Fragment that will lead to another activity when I clicked the Image Button

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-fragments, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to make my ImageButton to change into another activity when I click the button but I do not know how can I be able to do that on a fragment page.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AboutFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="About"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</FrameLayout>
```

JAVA code:

```
package com.example.voiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link AboutFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 *
 */
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {
    

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment AboutFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static AboutFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AboutFragment fragment = new AboutFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public AboutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    }
}
```

I'm new at Android Studio and the version that I'm currently using is 4.1.3
and I'm not familiar with coding in fragment since I do code usually on activity.
I'm struggling on assigning on fragmentJava
And I also followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiphbOtSyWY&t=244s for context of why I had fragment in my project file. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

So for fragment below code maybe helpful. First of all you should remove all the unnecessary stuffs [1] And next change the way you inflate your fragment [2]. And for your imagebutton call like this[3]. And then in onCreateView you can call your imagebutton from XML file like this[4]. And Thats all hope this works if you have any doubts do let me know.

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

[1] Remove from here to -    


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment AboutFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static AboutFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    AboutFragment fragment = new AboutFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public AboutFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}


--> TO here remove all the above stuffs

private ImageButton imagebutton;[3]

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    [2]
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);// Remove this 
    //And replace with the below 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    [4]
    imagebutton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
   
  }
}
```